# Switching glassfish 2.x to 3.1.1

Tags: java, glassfish

So I am managing a old java project that is using glassfish 2.x.
Seems like netbeans does not support 2.x versions any more, so I want to change it to 3.1.1.
How to properly make that change?

I have JDK 1.6 installed. When I try to select the 3.1.1 does not fix the error "Unable to find Application Server J2EE"

Thanks in advance. Sorry if this question is in the wrong place, this is really not my area.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a developer question. Try stackoverflow. Glassfish 3 ships with a upgrade tool. This will upgrade your domain - including all configuration like jndi, etc.